# Git clone remote: Repository not found

Tags: github, git-clone

I forked a private repo on github and tried to clone a copy on my computer but it said :

remote: Repository not found.

Does it mean I don't have permission to this repo? When I clicked on the collaborator button it says I have the option to leave the repo so I guess I have the permission.

What's wrong?

Comment: What specific command did you issue to clone the repo?

Comment: How are you trying to clone it ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my private repo (`Repository not found`) due to the fact that initially I logged in with an incorrect githab account. To fix it:

1. Open Control Panel from the Start menu
2. Select User Accounts
3. Select "Manage your credentials" in the left hand menu
4. Delete any credentials related to Git or GitHub

Comment: Wouldn't post an answer - OP hasn't been seen for over a year now

Answer (score 0):

My problem:
I created a new Github account and used the character '@' in my password.
While Github dosen't have an issue, but Git interpreats '@' as the end instruccion.
As a result, the repository name "not found".

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing your *specific* instruction, it's hard to say what's wrong. But running these commands should work if you have permissions:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/username/repository
```

Obviously, replace "username" and "repository" with their respective names. Also, to add your remote:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repository
```

`origin` can be named whatever you'd like it to be, though. I like to use my repository names rather than origin. So if I had a repository named "StackOverflow", I would say:

```
$ git remote add StackOverflow https://github.com/username/StackOverflow
```

Then to initialize, add code, commit code, and push:

```
$git init
$git add .
$git commit -m 'commit message'
$git push StackOverflow master
```

Hope this helped a bit.